# Third party logging module causing nginx to crash

Tags: nginx

I am using a third party module called Zlog for fast and more effective log printing. But now i keep getting the error message:worker process 50161 exited on singal 11(core dump). Then I used gdb backtrace, but it showed no problems. So does anyone know if Zlog is the cause of it? And if it is, is there a way to fix it? Or maybe recommend another good logging module thats supported by nginx.
Thank you

Comment: Well, if you added Zlog and Nginx is now crashing, then that's probably what caused it.  Did you install binaries or build from source?  In my usage of Nginx, I often had trouble with pre-built binaries.  When building from source (which goes rather quickly), I never had any trouble.  If you want a suggestion for other logging, it would be good to know what your requirements are.

Comment: @Brad I did install it from source, so thats probably not what caused it. For the logging, i need it to be mutliprocess safe, reliable, high-performance, pure C library. And can be redirected and reformatted easily. Thank you.

Comment: If it were me, I'd point the stock Nginx logger at a pipe and handle it outside of Nginx.  I use a similar setup where the logging data is buffered on disk and then sent to Log Stash regularly.